# how to set user type for lotus notes for a group, to create user and email account? using lotuscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

NotesRegistration.Mailaclmanager ="LocalDomainAdmins"

By Default, it always give me a **mixed Group**

How to set by default for for LocalDomainAdmins group is **[Person  group]**

[image]

My Coding update

```
Dim reg As New NotesRegistration

Dim dt As Variant
dt = DateNumber(Year(Today)+1, Month(Today), Day(Today))

reg.RegistrationServer = mailsvr    
reg.CreateMailDb = True                 '
reg.CertifierIDFile = certid        
reg.Expiration = dt
reg.IDType = ID_HIERARCHICAL
reg.MinPasswordLength = 1               
reg.IsNorthAmerican = True
reg.OrgUnit = OU        
reg.RegistrationLog = "log.nsf"
reg.UpdateAddressBook = True
reg.Storeidinaddressbook = false
reg.MailInternetAddress =  internetpath
reg.Shortname=doc.SelectMail(0) 
reg.Mailowneraccess =2      
reg.Mailcreateftindex=True      


Print mailfile
Print "pass 1"
Dim acl As NotesACL
Print "pass 1-1"
Dim aclEntry As NotesACLEntry
Print "pass 1-2"
Dim dbUser As NotesDatabase
Print "pass 1-3"
Set dbUser = New NotesDatabase(mailsvr,mailfile)    '   mail/person.nsf
Print "pass 1-4"
Set acl = dbUser.aCL
Print "pass 1-5"
Set aclEntry = acl.GetEntry("LocalDomainAdmins")
Print "pass 1-6"
aclentry.Usertype = ACLTYPE_PERSON_GROUP    '   cannot used
print "pass 1-7"
call acl.Save()
Print "pass 1-8"
```

result give some error on server side

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: Mail\yonna

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1-1

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1-2

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1-3

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1-4

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1-5

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent printing: pass 1-6

[0924:000A-0B88] 17/08/2017 09:59:46 AM  HTTP Server: Agent 'Register New User' error: Object variable not set

Comment: Are you SURE, you want to give a group containing admin- users the type "Server group"? You won't be able to access these databases with any admin- user anymore...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, my boss ask me to put it as [person group], but i put it wrongly. I not sure how to to write  Attribute-user type [person group] Cant find much information on help file. and internet source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change the type of the entry for Mailaclmanager within the NotesRegistration class.

You could do 2 things:

First: You go and get the database after the user is created and change the entry "manually":

```
Dim dbUser as NotesDatabase
Dim acl as NotesACL
Dim aclEntry as NotesACLEntry

'- do your registration here

Set dbUser = New NotesDatabase( usermailserver, usermailpath ) 
'- use variables for usermailserver and usermailpath that you use as parameters for registeruser
Set acl = dbUser.acl
Set aclEntry = acl.GetEntry( "LocalDomainAdmins" )
aclEntry.UserType = ACLTYPE_PERSON_GROUP
Call acl.Save()
```

Second: Just modify your templates ACL to contain the LocalDomainAdmins- Entry in Brackets (as [LocalDomainAdmins] ) with the correct type and access level: On creation of a database it copies all entries in Brackets from its template and removes the brackets.

I would prefer the first solution, as it does not need a manipulation of the template and all stuff is together at one place in the code.

Just one more thing: NEVER, and I repeat NEVER EVER write code without at least a minimal error handler. This is true for every coding language. A minimal error handler in Lotus Script looks like this:

```
On error goto ErrorHandler

'- your code goes here

EndOfRoutine:
  Exit sub 'or exit function
ErrorHandler:
  Print Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl
  Resume EndOfRoutine
```

Comment: I try the sample coding, It give me an object variable not set. I also update my question. Can you take a look of my code please. Thanks!

Comment: sorry.. I found my coding error already. Thanks for providing solution for this.

Comment: Just for anybody finding this: the error is, that without calling registeruser of notesregistration class there Is no database... the order of commands is simply wrong...

Comment: sorry..i dint put full code... actually got registeruser just i comment the "reg.Mailaclmanager="LocalDomainAdmins", so system can't find the group and fail the registration~ and of cuz you point the on error handler...thanks a lot for help~